# PHP GCM Undefined Index

Tags: php, android, google-cloud-messaging

On execution of my function, the error appears:

`[23-Apr-2015 01:08:39 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: syncNewData in C:\xampp\index.php on line 972`

for the line: `$pushMessageTag = isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : $_POST["syncNewData"];` in the function:

```
function updateDataGCM($db) {
    // Get all the GCM regIDs for anyone with new, "unseen" data:
    $sqlAllRegIds = 'select distinct gcm_registration_id 
                    from  users
                    where id in (
                    select distinct myId as usersID from  group_messages WHERE `read` = 1
                    UNION
                    SELECT distinct touid as usersID  from  messages where `read` = 1
                    UNION 
                    SELECT distinct invited_id as usersID from  event_invites where `status` = 1
                    UNION 
                    select distinct receiver_id as usersID from  group_invites where `status` = 1
                    UNION
                    select distinct requestId as usersID from  friends where `status` = 1
                    )';

    // Execute
    if ($resultIds = $db->query($sqlAllRegIds)) 
    {

        $pushMessageTag = isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : $_POST["syncNewData"]; 
        $gcmRegIds = array($resultIds);
        $message = array("syncNewData" => $pushMessageTag);
        $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);
        return $pushStatus; 
    }   

}
```

I do not understand why this error would occur, how to alleviate?

**UPDATE:**

This is the action that, upon a user sending a message, will send sync messages to GCM:

```
case "sendGroupMessage":
        if ($userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password, $gcmregid)) 
        {   
            if (isset($_REQUEST['toGroupId']))
            {   // instead of toUserName it's to a groupId
                $toGroupName = $_REQUEST['toGroupName'];
                $toGroupId   = $_REQUEST['toGroupId'];  
                $message     = $_REQUEST['messageText'];
                $campaign    = $_REQUEST['campaign_id'];
                $location    = $_REQUEST['location_id'];

                // Query to get the users id's who are in the group but not the user sending the message        
                $sqlGroupMembers = "SELECT DISTINCT usersId from users_groups 
                     WHERE usersId != '".$userId."' AND groupId = '".$toGroupId."'";


                // Loop to create a copy of message for all users taht are part of that group
                if($getGroupMembersId = $db->query($sqlGroupMembers)) 
                {
                    while($rowGroupMembers = $db -> fetchObject($getGroupMembersId))
                    {
                        $sql22 = "INSERT INTO `group_messages` ..."                 

                        error_log("$sql22", 3 , "error_log");
                        if ($db->query($sql22)) 
                        {

                            $out = SUCCESSFUL;

                        }               
                        else 
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;
                        }                   

                    }               


                }

                // Send GCM to turn on devices:
                echo updateDataGCM($db);                

            }
            else
            {
                $out = FAILED;
            }           

        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
```

The original updateDataGCM()

worked fine:

```
function updateDataGCM() {

    $gcmRegID  =  'test id'
    $pushMessage = $_POST["syncNewData"];   
    $gcmRegIds = array($gcmRegID);
    $message = array("syncNewData" => $pushMessage);
    $pushStatus = sendPushNotificationToGCM($gcmRegIds, $message);

    return $pushStatus;
}
```

Comment: is your form a POST method and does the element bear the name attribute of "syncNewData"? those are case-sensitive also, should you have made a typo.

Comment: plus this `isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : $_POST["syncNewData"];` that usually has a `''` instead `isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : '';`

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is no form, this is strictly in my PHP server and executed upon a user db aciton

Comment: so how is that POST come into play? the error's in your android code then, most likely. so again `syncNewData` isn't the same as `syncnewdata` should that be the case. what you posted isn't enough to throw that notice.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added the code that executes it, and the code that I used before that worked just fine, why would it throw an error now...

Comment: *Baffled* - Did you try `isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : '';`? or `isset($_REQUEST["syncNewData"]) ? $_REQUEST["syncNewData"] : '';`?

Comment: yes, i tried that and it sent the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST data doesn't include a variable called `syncNewData`. This line:

```
$pushMessageTag = isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : $_POST["syncNewData"];
```

which seems to be testing for the existence of that variable, will refer to `$_POST['syncNewData']` whether or not it is set.

You probably need

```
$pushMessageTag = isset($_POST["syncNewData"]) ? $_POST["syncNewData"] : '';
```

which will return the variable f it exists, or an empty string if it doesn't

Comment: I said that (twice actually) and they're saying they're still getting the same error.

Comment: @Fred well, either they've update the wrong code, or the same error is occurring separately elsewhere in their code and they haven't read the line numbers properly.  They'll have to figure it out for themselves now.

Comment: Yep, well Android stuff isn't something I know, although there is no Android code posted in their question; that I know for sure that it isn't. As to why it was tagged as such, I don't know. The error is most likely in their Android code and not in what they posted. That, along with the incorrect ternary.